# Whats wrong with Libgdx mesh transparancy?

Tags: java, graphics, opengl-es, libgdx

I have g3db model that consists of cylinder and "10gonal" prism inside cylinder. 
Prism material has texture and blending attributes, and cylinder has blending and color attribute with 0.5 transparency. And the problem is that looking from different sides "changes" cylinder transparency:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sPuh.jpg

And I need cylinder to be transparent from any point of view.

Comment: could be the order of paining vs. the z-buffer

Comment: @cfrick prism and cylinder are parts of same model and they are rendered using same shader. so the only thing that affects cylinder transparancy is camera position. Is it possible?

Comment: i'd say, that you should render the transparent parts last. looking at the left image i imagine, that the transparent part is rendered first and the "stony"-part later and is sorted out due to zbuffer checks.

Comment: Add the following code to your create method: `DefaultShader.defaultCullFace = 0; DefaultShader.defaultDepthFunc = 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually @cfrick was right. I found that libgdx's DefaultRenderableSorter changes rendering order according to mesh translation and camera position. And due to cylinder is a solid, and every side of prism is separate renderable calculation was wrong. Will write my own particular RenderableSorter.
 Thank you.